# How do I turn multiple strings into one?

Tags: php, string, shopping-cart

I built my own shopping cart, and I need to convert all the product ids in the cart into one string.

**Edit:**

I maybe asked unclear.

Heres my source:

```
                $sub_total=0;
                foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_products WHERE product_id ='$id'");
                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                if($rows['product_id']==$id){

                    $product_title=$rows['product_title'];
                    $product_id=$rows['product_id'];
                    $quantity=$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];
                    $price=$rows['product_price'];
                    $total_price=$price*$quantity;
                    $sub_total=$sub_total+$total_price;

                    /*======PRODUCT URL============*/
                    $product_category_id=$rows['product_category_id'];
                    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_categories WHERE category_id = '$product_category_id'");
                    $rows2=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    $category_url=$rows2['category_url'];
                    $product_url=$rows['product_url']
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right: 30px;"><a href="<?php echo "/store/$category_url/$product_url";?>"><?php echo $product_title;?></a></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 30px;">€ <?php echo $price;?></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 30px;">€ <?php echo $total_price;?></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 30px">
                                <a title="-1" href="/cartquantitydown/<?php echo $product_id;?>" style="color: red;text-decoration: none;">< </a>
                                <?php echo $quantity;?>
                                <a title="+1" href="/cartquantityup/<?php echo $product_id;?>" style="color: green;text-decoration: none;"> ></a>
                                <a href="/cartremoveitem/<?php echo $rows['product_id'];?>"><img title="Remove item" class="img" style="height: 20px;" src="/images/store/remove-icon.png"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php


                    }
                    }
                    }
```

I add a product to the cart using

```
 $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['quantity']++;
```

So how can I get all the product ids and qunatitys into one string?

Anyway I could place a array outside this code, if you know what I mean?

Comment: Use concatenation !!! You assigned `$productid` multiple times as well. *Why join bits of string instead of writing the whole string and putting it in a variable?*

Comment: Just as a starter, you should probably be using arrays if you're allowing multiple products in a shopping cart.

Comment: This is really a bad approach to this.  Use objects or use arrays, anything except trying to store multiple products with quantity into a long concatenated string.  Really, it seems to me that you should familiarize yourself with object-oriented programming techniques, as this problem would probably best be solved with a cart object which contains product objects.

Comment: I cant write the whole string as one. I built my own shopping cart using sessions and foreach loops to display them on the cart page.

Comment: You are supposed to use an `array`. String is a bad way of storing that information.

Comment: You never know, there could be a good reason to put them into a long string like that. I have to do that all the time to pass data into ancient COBOL programs...

Comment: I found the solution myself.

    `$quantityAndId.='1-'.'1553,';
    $quantityAndId.='4-'.'42645,';
    $quantityAndId.='2-'.'64561,';
    echo $quantityAndId;` Outputs 1-1553,4-42645,2-64561,

Comment: If you don’t know enough basics to figure out something that trivial yourself … then you should __not__ be writing your “own shopping cart” yet.

Answer (score 2):

use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)

```
$productids = array(
    '6_41',
    '4_645',
    '1_534',
    '1_5',
    '1_635',
    '1_124'
);
echo implode('-', $productids); // "6_41-4_645-1_534-1_5-1_635-1_124"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exact what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate them:

```
$productids = $productid1 . "-" . $productid2
```

Comment: I cant assing them as $product1, $product2, $product3.

Comment: Then however you have them assigned will work. You can also concatenate array elements, or use implode as @zwacky suggested.